# How to inject code in class and assign values to class fields at runtime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass, python-internals

I have a BatchJob specification file (batch.spec) something like below:

```
python = <<EOF

def foo():
    return f"foo: I am {self.name}"

def bar():
    return f"bar: I am {self.name}"

EOF

<batch>
  name p&l_calculator
  exec echo %foo()%
</batch>
```

I am converting this file to a python dict by using https://github.com/etingof/apacheconfig

```
from apacheconfig import *

with make_loader() as loader:
    config = loader.load('batch.spec')

# Print content of python dict
for key, value in config.items():
    print(key, value)

# output from print statement above
# python 
# def foo():
#     return f"foo: I am {self.name}"
#
# def bar():
#     return f"bar: I am {self.name}"
# batch {'name': 'p&l_calculator', 'exec': 'echo %foo()%'}
```

Now I am converting this python dict to a BatchJobSpec object like below:

```
class BatchJobSpec:

    def __init__(self, pythoncode , batch):
        self.pythoncode = pythoncode
        self.name = batch.get("name")
        self.exec = batch.get("exec")

batchjobspec = BatchJobSpec(config.get("python"), config.get("batch"))
```

If I print batchjobspec fields, then I will get something like below

```
print(batchjobspec.pythoncode)
print(batchjobspec.name)
print(batchjobspec.exec) 

# Output from above print statements
# def foo():
#     return f"foo: I am {self.name}"
#
# def bar():
#     return f"bar: I am {self.name}"
# p&l_calculator
# echo %foo()%
```

**Problem:** I want the value of "batchjobspec.exec" to be interpolated when I try to access it, i.e. it should not be "echo %foo()%" but it should be "echo foo: I am p&l_calculator".

i.e. somehow in the getter of fields, I want to check if there is "% %" syntax. If yes, and if content inside "% %" contains a callable then I want to call that callable and append the value returned from callable to the value of the corresponding field. I guess I will have to make these callables available in the BatchJobSpec dict as well.

Comment: Looks like a simple `string.replace('%...%', name)`

Comment: @stovfl yes replacement part is simple but the callable (function foo and bar in the example above) won't be available directly in the BatchJobSpec class dict. Callables are present as formatted string inside field "pythoncode".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Comment**:  I have foo as well as bar. exec(str) will execute both

In your `self.pythoncode` you have definitons of functions like `def foo():`. Therefore `exec` doesn't **execute** but do **define** these functions in the local namespace. To **execute** these functions as a `class methode`, you have to create a `attribute`, referencing these local functions, in the `class` itself.

1. In this example, the function names are known beforhand

   ```
   class BatchJobSpec:
       def __init__(self, pythoncode , batch):
           self.pythoncode = pythoncode
           self.name = batch['name']
           self._exec = ['for', 'bar']
           self.exec()
   ```
2. To make `self` visible in the local namespace, define the `locals_` dict.
   `exec` the string `self.pythoncode` results in insert the reference to the functions into `locals_`. To use these local references, as a `class methode` and make it persistent, use `self.__setattr__(...`.

   ```
       def exec(self):
           locals_ = {'self': self}
           exec(self.pythoncode, locals_)
           for attrib in self._exec:
               print('__setattr__({})'.format(attrib))
               self.__setattr__(attrib, locals_[attrib])
   ```
3. **Usage**: Different python `format` syntax, as i using python 3.5

   ```
   python = """
   def foo():
       return 'foo: I am {name}'.format(name=self.name)

   def bar():
       return 'bar: I am {name}'.format(name=self.name)
   """

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       batchjobspec = BatchJobSpec(config.get("python"), config.get("batch"))
       print('echo {}'.format(batchjobspec.foo()))
       print('echo {}'.format(batchjobspec.bar()))
   ```
4. > **Output**:
   >
   > ```
   > __setattr__(foo)
   > __setattr__(bar)
   > echo foo: I am p&l_calculator
   > echo bar: I am p&l_calculator
   > ```

---

> **Question**  I want the value of "batchjobspec.exec" to be interpolated when I try to access it

- [library/functions - `exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)
- [`object.__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__)

---

Change your `class BatchJobSpec` to:

```
class BatchJobSpec:

    def __init__(self, pythoncode , batch):
        self.pythoncode = pythoncode
        self.name = batch.get("name")
        self._exec = batch.get("exec")

    @property
    def exec(self):
        to_exec = 'foo'
        self.__setattr__(to_exec, lambda : exec('print("Hello world")'))

        self.foo()
        return None
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but please note that the functions "foo" and "bar" are not present in the class. They are inside field "self.pythoncode", how can I get these functions injected to the class? Do I need to add setter for pythoncode field and update class dict from there?

Comment: foo is already there in the self.pythoncode, I dont want to create any new foo.

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal: **No**, in the `.pythoncode` is a `str`, the created `self.foo` is a reference to this string executed thru `exec(<code>)`

Comment: exec will execute all the code in the str. There can be many functions in str. As an example check in my question I have foo as well as bar. exec(str) will execute both.

Comment: Can you please generalize this solution, without assuming that there will be only foo and bar functions.

Comment: *"without assuming that there will be only"*: There is **no assumption**? `self.pythoncode` can hold unlimited functions definitions.

Comment: What is the final change that I should make?    Logic inside  

@property
def exec(self):  is unclear to me.

Comment: I mean a final change including all the logic would help me understand what is going on. i.e. if someone gives me "exec echo %foo()%" and there is a pythoncode in self, how do I ensure to return "echo foo: I am p&l_calculator" when I access self.exec.

Comment: I appreciate all the logic that you have written but I am unable to connect these dots.

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal: The first example at the bottom using `@property` was a simple how to. **Forget about it**, use only the second example at the top, it's full working.

Comment: In the second example at the top "for attrib in self._exec:" self._exec has foo and bar only because you initialized this in init. How can I make this generic?

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal: We have reached our comments limit. It's to broad for SO, setup a [GitHubGist](https://gist.github.com) there i can extend the code to your needs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189344/discussion-between-lokesh-agrawal-and-stovfl).